# Creating JS array from JSON

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I have the following AJAX function in jQuery:

```
$.post('../../afisare.php', {"fac_name" : facility_name }, function(response) {
            alert(response);
});

$.ajax({
    url: "../../afisare.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(json){
        console.log(json);
    }
});
```

And the following encoding in a php file:

```
$facility_name = $_POST['fac_name'];

$facility_data = getFacilities($facility_name);
$facility_data2 = json_encode($facility_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
print($facility_data2);
```

The array in the php file ($facility_data2) prints exactly as it should.

My question is: how do I create a javascript array in the succes function that contains the exact elements as the JSON?

Edit: added the $.post function also; The alert prints the JSON as it should, but the `console.log(json)` prints an empty array. To clarify: the JSON is generated based on what the `getFacilities` function returns.

Later edit: for anyone who has the same issue as I did (best advice: read the documentation thoroughly), here is the function that works:

```
$.post('../../afisare.php', {"fac_name" : facility_name }, function(json) {
    data = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(data[0].facility_name);
});
```

The problem with my previous attempt was that I wasn't using the callback function in the $.post function as I should have (e.g. this function is directly linked to the variables that I am posting to the php file, thus being unable to be read from outside that function).

Comment: print out facility data

Comment: The funtion parameter `json` will contain whatever you echo out from your PHP script. I am pretty sure you dont want the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` and fairly sure you dont need the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` parameters in that `json_encode()` function either. Because you have a `dataType: "JSON"` the json parameter will be converted automatically to a javascript data type matching that sent from the PHP i.e an object or an array

Comment: I used the JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES because the array contains some links that get messed up with backslashes. Edited the main post for clarificaitons.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = [];

for(var i in json)
    result.push([i, json [i]]);
```

Comment: `result` still returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('../../afisare.php', {"fac_name" : facility_name }, function(json) {
    data = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(data[0].facility_name);
});
```

The problem with my previous attempt was that I wasn't using the callback function in the $.post function as I should have (e.g. this function is directly linked to the variables that I am posting to the php file, thus being unable to be read from outside that function).